# Does anyone use Flutter to build an SDK for Android/iOS Application

Tags: sdk, flutter

I need to build an SDK included many business features for other Android and iOS Application products.
Can I use Flutter or ReactNative or something else to do it? Does anyone have experiences about this? Please explain to me!
Thank you.

Comment: It's probably better to use C, Go, Rust, ... and then integrate it using JNI on Android and I assume Object-C and Swift have similar mechanism. Flutter is more an UI framework. If you want to build UI widgets in Flutter and integrate them in iOS and Android apps, that should be supported.

Comment: @Hưng hello, i have the same question , could you find any solution?

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer thanks for your comment. im asked to generate an aar file from flutter project (which are not ui , all are business classes) in order to use in native java android and native xcode ios project. do you think it is possible or is it a standard way?
I'm really stocked and can not find any solution

Answer (score 0):

As [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) suggested in the comments you should use another language for better performance. Anyways, you can make use of a flutter package. [Create a package](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/) where you define some sort of UI that you will call later as a widget and will lay on top of it in the widget tree.

Then, when you create a new Flutter Application you include the package, set everything and call your children. With a tree like that:

```
- Flutter App
    - Created package with UI and code
        - specifications and options
        - rest of the Flutter App
```